# Some unicode symbols still not displayed with urxvt or xterm

Tags: fonts, xorg, arch-linux, unicode, urxvt

I've been having trouble viewing certain unicode symbols under urxvt or xterm. The font I'm using is `Source Code Pro for Powerline` which I installed through the powerline fonts repo. My `.Xresources` contains the following:

```
  9 URxvt.font: xft:Source\ Code\ Pro\ for\ Powerline:pixelsize=22,xft:PowerlineSymbols
 10 URxvt.scrollBar: false
 11 
 12 Xft.dpi: 150
 13 Xft.antialias: true
 14 Xft.rgba: rgb
 15 Xft.hinting: true
 16 Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
 17 
 18 XTerm*selectToClipboard: true
 19 XTerm*termName: xterm-256color
 20 XTerm*locale: true
 21 XTerm*metaSendsEscape: true
 22 UXTerm*faceName: Source Code Pro for Powerline:style=Medium
 23 UXTerm*faceSize:10
```

but I still get funky behavior like in the following circumstances

[image]
[image]
[image]

`$TERM` outputs `rxvt-unicode-256color`

Running `urxvt --help 2>&1 | grep options:` returns `iso14755`, `unicode3`, and `frills` among other things.

So I'm unsure why I still can't see some of these unicode symbols because I have all my bases covered? This is happening system-wide as I can't see certain symbols in Firefox either, so I think it has to be a font issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

What I do here to get the glyphs I need working on urxvt is to add more fonts in the font list:

```
URxvt.font: xft:Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=18:antialias=true:hinting=true,\
            xft:Source Code Pro:pixelsize=18:style=medium:antialias=true,\
            -*-unifont-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

It is still not perfect, though. I still can't get everything properly displayed in this file: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-demo.txt

What helped the most so far with most unicode glyphs I use frequently was the inclusion of Unifont in the list. I hope it helps you in some way.

As for xterm, it doesn't support multiple fonts.

To discover which font provides a certain glyph, I use gucharmap (available on linux distros at least), hit `Ctrl-f`, `C-s-u <unicode codepoint>` (ex: `C-s-u2713` which is ✓) and then I right-click on the glyph found and the app shows the name of the font used to render that specific glyph.

Answer (score 5):

Fernando Basso's answer already helped me a lot. However, as he also pointed out, I still could not get all the glyphs to work. Especially the symbol indicating the line in airline (㏑) didn't work until I added the *ttf version* of Unifont.

The ttf version can be installed with `apt install ttf-unifont` on Debian (probably it's a different package name in other distributions). After that I added the ttf version of Unifont as an extra entry to my `~/.Xdefaults`:

```
URxvt.font:            xft:Hack:pixelsize=18,\
                       xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:pixelsize:18,\
                       xft:Unifont:pixelsize:16,\
                       -*-unifont-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
```

As you can see, it's possible to load both the bitmap and ttf version.